# Jenkins - how to create list field parameter using shell script

Tags: deployment, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm having a free-style project in Jenkins. and I want to run a pre-script (bash) that will get list of running instances (from aws ec2) and loads them into a multi-select parameter in jenkins.

I have the script ready but I can't figure where to put it.
no matter what I do I can't get this right.

Can someone please explain me what i'm missing?

Comment: `Active Choice` or `Dynamic *` or `EnvInject` or `Extended Choice` parameter plugins and using Groovy code to populate those variables by fetching the ec2 servers/list, you can achieve that. If you can't get Groovy tiny script working and still want to use the Shell shenzi then, I'd say, create a Jenkins job (where in the build step you'll run your Shell script using Build step `Execute shell`), then create an output file in that job's workspace. Now, In another Jenkins job where you want to use the contents/output as possible choices, you can use that file's output to populate that variable.

Answer (score 3):

This is old but just in case someone is looking for a solution:

Use the [Extensible Choice Parameter Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extensible-choice-parameter) to 
create a parametrised build. As the Choice Provider option, choose System Groovy Choice Parameter. To fetch a list of running instances, use the following Groovy script:

```
def command = "aws ec2 describe-instances --query [Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId] --output text"
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()              
def instances = proc.in.text.readLines()
return instances
```

Of course you need to have aws access configured on your Jenkins server.