# Can I query AWS ECR to populate an active choices reactive parameter in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I would like to use the active choices parameter plugin to search AWS ECR image tags and present a dynamic filtered list of the results as parameter options in a Jenkins declarative script based on another choice parameter.

Assuming my jenkins controller (and agent) node(s) have awscli installed and the necessary IAM role permissions to access the ECR repository, and there is a separate choiceParam named 'ENVIRONMENT', I'd like to run the following command:

```
aws ecr list-images --region us-east-1 --repository-name web-app --query "imageIds[?starts_with(imageTag,'${ENVIRONMENT}')].imageTag" --output text
```

and return the results displayed as the options to choose from in "Build with Parameters". I see evidence that others have managed to achieve this with an active choices reactive parameter but I have not managed to get it working.

If I shell into my Jenkins controller (docker container on k8s) and execute the above command I get the desired results no problem. After much experimentation in the groovy script console I have figured out the correct syntax for escaping quotes and have tried various renditions of groovy scripts along these lines:

```
def command = "aws ecr list-images --region us-east-1 --repository-name web-app --query \"imageIds[?starts_with(imageTag,\'${ENVIRONMENT}\')].imageTag\" --output text"
def output = command.execute()
def images = output.text.tokenize()
return images
```

The result of this script is [None], no matter what I change the $ENVIRONMENT choice param to. I am absolutely sure there should be results returned, as in there are images whose tags start with $ENVIRONMENT, and I can run the same awscli command in shell on my jenkins controller and see results.

I have tried approving scripts at jenkins_host/scriptApproval/ with "groovy sandbox" option turned on and off.

Based on other stackOverflow answers I've seen, I have tried numerous variations on wording for the 'command' line, including:

```
def command = "aws ecr list-images --region us-east-1 " + 
              "--repository-name web-app " +
              " --query \"imageIds[?starts_with(imageTag,\'${ENVIRONMENT}\')].imageTag\" "+ 
              "--output text"

// or 

def command = ["aws", "ecr", "list-images", "--region", "us-east-1", "--repository-name", "web-app", "--query", "\"imageIds[?starts_with(imageTag,\'${ENVIRONMENT}\')].imageTag\"", "--output", "text"]
```

All return the same result: `[None]`

What am I missing? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119238/jenkins-how-to-create-list-field-parameter-using-shell-script) it shows an example using aws cli command.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is wondering, I really struggled with this but eventually found that for some reason that I don't fully understand Jenkins was having trouble computing the query portion of the aws command. I couldn't get grep or jq to work either. So eventually I let groovy handle the filtering portion of the command and the following groovy script worked for me.

```
def cmd = "aws ecr list-images --region us-east-1 --repository-name app --output text"
def output = cmd.execute()
output.waitFor()
def imageList = output.in.text.tokenize().toUnique().sort().reverse()
def images = imageList.findAll { it =~ /^\$ENVIRONMENT-(.*)/ }
return images
```