# Jenkins parameters using groovy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, service-accounts

We have jenkins pipeline created and we trying to get list of GCP instance images for specific project with the help active choice parameter plugin and using below code after when we save the job it should show us list of gcp instance images for specific project but it is keep coming as blank , we need this drop down to be available as pre post building the pipeline.

We are not facing error when run the pipeline seems like by passing the code mentioned here in groovy.

Also we have created Service account to connect our GCP project to Jenkins.

Any clue , or any has done like this the let us know.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def cmd = "gcloud compute images list --project="xyz" --filter="xyz" | grep 'redhat84-gi'"
def gi_images_json = cmd.execute()
def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText(gi_images_json.text)
def gi_images = [];
return gi_images.sort().reverse
```

We are following below to mimic the same for GCP but this document says for AWS.
https://medium.com/@different.vinod/access-of-ecr-images-tags-as-active-choice-in-jenkins-for-deployments-8dcdbdbff996

Thanks
Mahendra

I am trying to get list of GCP instance images mentioned in a project with the help of groovy but I am not getting the list in dropdown it is keep coming as blank

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem trying to get image tags from (AWS) ECR repositories. I don't have an explanation for why but groovy `.execute` doesn't seem to like `|`s in the string scripts. No matter how I tried to escape them I couldn't get a pipe to grep or jq to work. I settled for getting all the image tags and then parsing them with regex in a groovy `.findAll()` [function](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#List-Filtering) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71651892/12356847).

Also, I only just noticed but you would really have to escape your quotes in the cmd string better. As written above in your question the string is "gcloud compute images list --project=" and then a garbled mess of text after it. That is definitely not going to work. Try:

```
def cmd = "gcloud compute images list --project=\"xyz\" --filter=\"xyz\" | grep 'redhat84-gi'"
```

Or leave them out altogether. They are not really needed in this particular circumstance because they aren't holding together complex strings which include white space. It's much easier to write without them. Like so:

```
def cmd = "gcloud compute images list --project=xyz --filter=xyz | grep redhat84-gi"
```